# How to find row index in a mat table with multiTemplateDataRows and paginator

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to have the rowindex so that I can use it in ngModel of my controls

My table : (before pagination feature is added)

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8">
....
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let rowIdx = dataIndex;">
...
<mat-select disableRipple class="go" [(ngModel)]="schedule.todo[rowIdx].notes"
                        name="some{{element}}">
```

and many more columns that use rowIdx

My pagination is working

> <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]" showFirstLastButtons
> aria-label="Select items per page">

The problem  is unable to calculate right index, as page 2 again starts with 0.

Is it possible to fix something in this line

> **<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let rowIdx = dataIndex; ???? ">**

and have a reusable row index ?

Comment: just use a template reference variable in your paginator (e.g. `#paginator`) and use some like `{{rowIdx+(paginator.pageIndex*paginator.pageSize)}}`

Comment: I already have this
    private paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
      this.paginator = mp;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    }

How can I use it ? I am not looking to print value like <...>{{index here}}</td>. I need for ngmodel

Comment: Goal: first column should get proper index into i . example Stackblitz showing indexes start 0 in every page - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uf9d5l?file=src/app/table-pagination-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify, what row index are you trying to get? If you have paginator at 5 and you are on page 1 you would have row id's from 1-5 present. For that I have implemented a way using `paginator` to calculate what index we are at and using `onContentChange` to detect changes when page has been moved.

```html
    <!-- ID Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let innerIndex = index" #something (click)="onClickItemId(row.id);onClickRowEvent(innerIndex)" style="background: green"> {{row.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>
```

```js
 @Component({
  selector: 'table-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-overview-example.html',
})
export class TableOverviewExample implements AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'progress', 'fruit'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserData>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
startingIndexOfPage: number;
endingIndexOfPage: number
clickedItemId: number;
count: number;
innerIndexCalculated: number;
  constructor() {
    // Create 100 users
    const users = Array.from({length: 100}, (_, k) => createNewUser(k + 1));

    // Assign the data to the data source for the table to render
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(users);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

  onContentChange(event: any) {
    this.getCurrentIndex()
  }

  getCurrentIndex() {
    this.startingIndexOfPage = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
    this.endingIndexOfPage = (this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize) + this.paginator.pageSize;
  }

  onClickItemId(itemId: number) {
    this.clickedItemId = itemId;
  }

  onClickRowEvent(innerIndex: number) {
   this.innerIndexCalculated = this.startingIndexOfPage + innerIndex + 1;
  }
}
```

```html
startingIndexOfPage: {{startingIndexOfPage}}
<br>
endingIndexOfPage: {{endingIndexOfPage}}
<br>
clickedItemId: {{clickedItemId}}
<br>
innerIndexCalculated: {{innerIndexCalculated}}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbwai9-wax11m?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-overview-example.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I do not get id in data to use like "<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </td>" <-- row.id is not available. I captured this point in my stackblitz . I click on rows, so I need  real  index to get data from a list.

Comment: hope I explained why I need actual row id (as i click on row to find other json elements at that index)

Comment: I think I understand. You want to get the rowId when you click on a row, but the problem was that when using a paginator internal row id starts again from zero. For that I have implemented a solution as following. We get which `nth` row the user as clicked on and then we add the start of paginator index to it. Say a user is on range 40-50 and clicks on the 7th row we would get rowId 47. I have also demonstrated other way of using `clickedItemId` to read the actual itemId itself which could be more useful to traverse and find an object rather than using table row id - which will change.

Comment: I have updated my answer and demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbwai9-wax11m?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-overview-example.html

Comment: Thanks for your effort.  I did look at the answer , but I am looking more around (1) let i =rowIdx  normal case (2) let i = dataIndex  for multitemplatedatarows (3) ? for pagination multitemplatedatarow.  I have many columns and index is key as I use it in ngModel.  I need non-event based without click (or) I give up pagination. If innerindex has right index then I need  like this {{innerIndex}}:: <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let innerIndex = index" #something (click)="onClickItemId(row.id);onClickRowEvent(innerIndex)" style="background: green"> {{innerIndex}} </td>